# applique texture using glTextCoordPointer

Tags: c++, qt, opengl, textures

I'm drawing my points like that :

```
TAB_PAS = 2;

glVertexPointer(TAB_PAS,GL_FLOAT,0,test[0].send_terrain());
glDrawElements( GL_LINES, indice_degra_de.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indice_degra_de.constData());
glVertexPointer(TAB_PAS,GL_FLOAT,0,test[1].send_terrain());
glDrawElements( GL_LINES, indice_degra.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indice_degra.constData());
glVertexPointer(TAB_PAS,GL_FLOAT,0,test[2].send_terrain());
glDrawElements( GL_LINES, indice_degra_de.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indice_degra_de.constData());
glVertexPointer(TAB_PAS,GL_FLOAT,0,test[3].send_terrain());
```

It draws a big terrain.

So now, I want for exemple applique a floor texture. I saw a function `glTexCoordPointer` but I don't know how to use it:

```
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, test[0].send_terrain()); 
// Something like that ?
```

I already uploaded my picture.tga, so now the problem is to applique it.

Answer (score 0):

You use `glTextCoordPointer` in the same way as `glVertexPointer` :

```
glVertexPointer(TAB_PAS, GL_FLOAT, 0, test[0].send_terrain());
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, test[0].send_texCoords());
glDrawElements(GL_LINES, indice_degra_de.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indice_degra_de.constData());
```

You need to specify the texture coordinates in another array, where every pair of texture coordinates correspond to one vertex in your terrain data.

To have OpenGL actually use your Texture Coordinates:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY); // Before calling DrawElements
```

And of course you must have the texture bound and enabled. Complete example, assuming you generate texture coordinates and have your .tga texture uploaded to OpenGL:

```
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureHandle);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

glVertexPointer(TAB_PAS,GL_FLOAT,0,test[0].send_terrain());
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, text[0].send_texCoord());
glDrawElements( GL_LINES, indice_degra_de.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indice_degra_de.constData());

glVertexPointer(TAB_PAS,GL_FLOAT,0,test[1].send_terrain());
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, text[1].send_texCoord());
glDrawElements( GL_LINES, indice_degra.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indice_degra.constData());

glVertexPointer(TAB_PAS,GL_FLOAT,0,test[2].send_terrain());
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, text[2].send_texCoord());
glDrawElements( GL_LINES, indice_degra_de.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_INT, indice_degra_de.constData());

glVertexPointer(TAB_PAS,GL_FLOAT,0,test[3].send_terrain());
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, text[3].send_texCoord());
// and so on...
```

I hope this is what you need

Comment: Thanks you. And how you calculate the tex Coord ?

Comment: Here is a short tutorial about textures. It ends with an example of texture coordinates: http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/opengl/opengl-texture-mapping-an-introduction-r947